# Passing slot to slot

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs-slots

I am building a small library which would allow modifying parts of the application layout from within other components.

The basic idea is that having a main navigation component:

```
<template>
  <div class='main-navigation>
    <div class='logo'><img...>
    <div class='actions'>
      <Container name='extra-actions' />
      <a href="some-action">Action</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

Component could then register additional content with:

```
<template>
  <div class='home-page'>
    <ContentFor container="extra-actions">
      <a href='some-home-specific-action'>Do sth extra</a>
    </ContentFor>

    ...rest of the page
  </div>
</template>
```

I've managed to get the above to work, using custom plugin and service object registering (and updating) slots as VNode as defined in ContentFor and rendering it within a container. I'd like now to enhance it by allowing user to add a custom layout per content given, for example:

```
<ul class='actions'>
  <Container name='extra-actions'>
    <li><slot></slot></li>
  </Container>
</ul>
```

This would nicely decouple the view component from the navigation structure. I've tried the following:

```
render (h) {
  return h(Fragment, Object.values(this.contents).map((content) => {
    if (this.$scopedSlots.default) {
      return this.$scopedSlots.default({
        slots: { default: content.slot } # this does nothing!
      })
    } else {
      # This works as expected
      return content.slot
    }
  }))
},
```

The above works just fine when there is no custom template. When custom template is present, it render that template, but does not pass the content to template's slot, resulting in:

```
<ul class='actions'>
  <li></li> # instead of <li><a href='some-home-specific-action'>Do sth extra</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any specific way scopes can be passed to other scopes?

Comment: I doubt a slot can have another slot(s) as direct child. Have you tried with templates instead of render functions ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV - Render function is much more robust than template (which is compiled onto render function anyway). The problem seems to be that since `<slot>` is used in the context of the parent, it is populated with a content of Navigation tag. I agree that slot will not work here, but the question is: what will?

Comment: Render functions are imperative while templates are declarative - it is always easier to understand declarative than imperative code. Perhaps if you try to build your intention with template(s) only - it will help you to convert the solution into render function(s) ...

Comment: @IVOGELOV - The problem here is that I am looping over a collection of VNodes. There is no way to use them directly using template syntax (would need to create a custom functional component for that) so I am stuck with render function somewhere. In the end though, I had to create such a component anyway and I am passing VNodes through scopedSlots into template slots (Where those vNodes has to be passed to that component). It's ugly as hell, but it seems to be no cleaner way out.

Comment: I understand. Still, it seems to me that you are overcomplicating the things. Anyway, from my point of view, if you have 2 components - component 1 as `<ul><slot/></ul>` and component 2 as `<li><slot/></li>` and then you want to compose them as `<component1><component2>text</component2><component2>other</component2></component1>` it should be obvious that you first create component 2 instances, after that - component 1, and only at the end - the top-level wrapper where you are rendering the above sequence.

Comment: This will not work in this case - Container might be used in a long living component (like main navigation, common for all the routes) and ContentFor will be used in short-living view components. So Container is responsible here for handling multiple contents during its life-cycle. 

Whether it is overcomplicated or not, it's a separate discussion - it provides flexible abstraction that can be used in multiple places for cross-component communication/rendering.

Comment: This is probably a different case than yours but it may still be interesting to read -  https://michaelnthiessen.com/advanced-vue-controlling-parent-slots 
 https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/dynamic-vue-layout-components/

Answer (score 1):

So after going back and forth with this I've learnt this is not possible to solve my templating with a slot. When I do

```
# layout/Navigation.vue
<ul>
  <Container name='main-nav-actions>
    <li><slot/></li>
  </Container>
</ul>
```

`</slot>` is being resolved in the context of the Navigation component - meaning it is a static array of VNodes at this point. Due to this, slots cannot have their own dynamic, nested slots.

Instead, I had to write a functional component responsible for rendering VNodes:

```
export {
  name: 'RenderContent',
  functional: true,
  render (h, { props }) { return props.content }
}
```

With that exposed, I can now build my template using scopedSlot:

```
  <Container name='main-nav-actions vue-slot="{ content }">
    <li><RenderContent :content="content"></li>
  </Container>
```

This is not the prettiest solution, but it seems to work, allows passing optional options through ContentFor which is quite great.